# WPF: Application crashes during textchange in windows 10 japanese

Tags: c#, wpf

In my textchanged event, there is a regex.replace method where it replaces any matching characters into empty strings and then sets the return value to a textbox. It also replaces japanese characters into empty strings as well
This is working fine in windows 7 however in I started to input a japanese character in windows 10, the system started to crash.

Comment: Source code? Error message? Need a lot more information

Comment: I was also able to replicate this situation, with the application crashing with a `FatalExecutionEngineError`. A potential workaround could be to use the `LostFocus` event rather than the `TextChanged` event.